# Click GUI Button From Bash Script

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to make a bash script to install command line tools for OSX Mavericks. Following the tutorial [here](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/) it says to type `xcode-select --install` from terminal. Putting it into a bash script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

xcode-select --install
```

I want to automate this even further to require minimal human input, is there a way to have the bash script click on the 'install' button (step 4) that pops up afterwards?

Comment: you would need to employ applescript to perform this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is not the right tool for the job. What you should look at, in order, is

1. Additional flags or settings for `xcode-select` to install without user interaction
2. Another tool or package that allows installing the same thing without user interaction.
3. A UI scripting tool for your platform that allows recognizing buttons by ID in a robust way
4. Finally, when all else fails, kludge it with Bash

For the latter, you can install and use `xdotool` to simulate button presses:

```
xcode-select --install &
sleep 5
xdotool key Tab Tab Return
```

Comment: Isn't this a chicken vs egg problem? How do you install xdotool without homebrew / a working build env?

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript allows GUI scripting:

- http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/as_related_apps.html

It may be able to do what you wish to do.